# I want my timer to run in background but it stops as soon it goes in background android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, timertask

**## This main activity class ##**

**> Suggest me with suitable answer**

```
pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            time = pref.getInt("key1", 300);
            if (time == 300) {
```

****getting initial values from shred preferances****

```
                number.setText("01:00:00");
                startTimer(time, false);
            } else {
                startTimer(time, false);
            }
        }

        private void prepareView() {

        }

        private void setOnListener() {

            btnLunchOUT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    startTimer(time, true);
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            btnLunchIN.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }, 2000);



}
            });
```

**Here m storing the value of stopped time in shared preferences**

```
  btnLunchIN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    countdownTask.cancel();
                    btnLunchIN.setEnabled(false);

                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            btnLunchOUT.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }, 3000);
                    btnReset.setEnabled(true);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Timer Stopped",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    flag = false;

                    pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);**
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
                    edit.putInt("key", time);
                    edit.commit();

                }
            });
```

**** Getting Value of starting time from Shared Prefrences****

```
            btnReset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (!flag) {

                        // countdownTask.cancel();
                        btnReset.setEnabled(false);
                        btnLunchOUT.setEnabled(true);
                        btnLunchIN.setEnabled(false);
                        flag = false;
                        time = 300;
                        number.setText("00:00:00");// Reset Timing Format
                        pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
                        edit.putInt("key", 300);
                        edit.commit();
                    }
                }
            });
        }



        @Override
        public void onResume() { ## OnResume method where i think its problem but i m unable to trace it

            System.out.println("In Resume");
            super.onResume();
            pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            time = pref.getInt("key", time);
            number.setText("" + time);

            s = (time) % 60;
            m = ((time) / 60) % 60;
            h = 00;
            number.setText("0" + h + ":" + m + ":" + s);



            startTimer(time, false);
        }


    ## **onPause method** ##
        @Override
        public void onPause() { 

            System.out.println("Timer Pause:");
            pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit(); // Saving the value of timer in shared preferences
            edit.putInt("key", time);
            edit.commit();

            super.onPause();

        }
    ## Here my timer starts on start button click
        public void startTimer(int value, boolean isStartButton) {

            time = value;
            Log.e("ONMAIN:: ", "" + time);
            if (isStartButton) {
                countdownTask = new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                        time--; // ***Here i split 300 into HH:MM:SS format***
                            s = (time) % 60;
                                m = ((time) / 60) % 60;
                                h = 00;

                                System.out.println("In Run" + time);
```

**> Enabled sound and vibrator on remianing 60 seconds**

```
                if (s < 10) {
                                    if (m < 10) {
                                        number.setText("0" + h + ":" + 0 + m + ":"
                                                + 0 + s);
                                    }
                                } else if (s < 10) {
                                    number.setText("0" + h + ":" + m + ":" + 0 + s);
                                } else if (m < 10) {
                                    number.setText("0" + h + ":" + 0 + m + ":" + s);
                                }

                                else {
                                    number.setText("0" + h + ":" + m + ":" + s);

                                }
                                btnLunchOUT.setEnabled(false);

                                btnReset.setEnabled(false);

                                if (time == 60) {
                                    vibrate = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

                                    vibrate.vibrate(pattern, -1);

                                    soundalert.start();
                                    System.out.println("1 Minute Remianing ");
                                }

                                if (time == 1) {

                                    countdownTask.cancel();


                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
                Timer countdown = new Timer(); //This is timer 
                countdown.scheduleAtFixedRate(countdownTask, 0, 1000);
                flag = false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: you want sound or alarm ?? because either you can play sound or give notification at some scheduled time or event.please elaborate question..

Comment: sound and vibration alert when activity is destroyed after setting alarm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution to make a timer run on background is doing it through a `Service`. 
Create a `Service`, which you start (and pass to it the instance of your timer) on the `onPause` method and you destroy it(and retrieve the timer) on the `onResume` method when you brin your main activity on top.

**EDIT:**

```
public class TimerService extends Service {

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       Log.i("SERVICE", "CREATED");
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();   
       Log.i("SERVICE", "DESTROYED");
       //Save your timer instance on destroy service
   }

   @Override
   public void onLowMemory() {
       super.onLowMemory();
       Log.i("SERVICE", "LOW MEMORY");
   }


   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     //Retrieve the timer instance here and use it... 

       //Restart service if Android destroys it!
       return Service.START_NOT_STICKY; 
   } 
}
```

In your main activity, in `onPause` start the service (`onPause` is called when activity goes in background):

```
Intent inetnt=new Intent(this, TimerService.class);
intnet.putExtra("Timer", YourTimerInstance); //Instance as string or int...
startService(inetnt);
```

In your main activity, in `onResume` (called when your activity comes in foreground again) stop the service and retrieve the instance from it. To do this you can use `SharedPreferences` (there are thounsands examples of `SharedPreferences` in google). To start the service:

```
Intent inetnt=new Intent(this, TimerService.class);
//Retrieve timer instance
stopService(inetnt);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you show me some to code to make service because i m new to android

Comment: My timer runs in background but as soon as it comes in foreground the timer start from the value when it was send in back ground. For example timer went to background on 00:4:50 and after 20 seconds i bring my application to foreground and its shud start from 00:04:30 but the timer starts from 00:04:50 so please do help me regarding this problem also.

Comment: Check the edit. Save the timer instance (time) in the moment when you start the service, not at the bigining of activity. If you save it at the biggining in a static way you will always have same value (00:04:50)

Comment: what is this iddle service class ?

Comment: Sorry, name mistake. It means TimerService.class. Check update

Comment: i m saving the time value in shared preferences only in onPause and onResume method so now i should do it in service class ..??

Comment: you should save your time in SharedPreferences when you bring activity in foreground and destroy your service. So save time in onDestroy in the service and get time in onResume in the activity after the destroy service code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51250/discussion-between-yash-5111-and-margabro)

Comment: My timer working perfectly but now in same timer I to want start another in continuation with that timer runs for 30 minutes and stops automatically.and yes timer goes in negative values like (-1,-2,-3 ..so on ) Suggest some help